# How can I make negative border radius with CSS ONLY?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I post this thread, because I need help for something please. I would like to create negative border radius for my navigation links (like this): http://prntscr.com/9vi0b5

As you can see, there is normal border radius at the top, but at the bottom, we have negative border radius. On the image above, two images are used to make the effect, but I want something with CSS only please. Something that I can edit when I want, you know?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "negative border radius"?

Comment: Reversed border radius like the image.

Comment: Your question is similar to this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421666/css-borders-with-negative-radius.

Comment: This got closed before I had chance to finish my answer but perhaps something like this would work: https://jsfiddle.net/uos2Lkhz/3/

Comment: example used here once http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RWyGWL box-shadow draws the shape/colors it is upside down, but technic is the same. you can even animate and give differentes shapes

Comment: This was supposed to be my answer with a single element. Tested on Chrome only [https://jsfiddle.net/pfsdbbc5/](https://jsfiddle.net/pfsdbbc5/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible.

But a solution could be to use `:before` and `:after` to build this effect.

Something like

```
:before {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

:after {
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know and I will use that, but in the ::before and ::after, I need to put something for the effect. This can't be empty.

Comment: What effect ? You mean `content: " "` ?

Comment: Nope, something to build the negative border radius effect. I think I need to use gradients.

Comment: I edited answer to be more explicit